# How to distribute a working php webpage through windows office network with limited user rights?

Tags: php, sql, windows, oracle, webserver

I have developed a table based view.php, which consists of a local mysql database part, that does a remote left join on external oracle databases (read-only) from our partner company.
All **working fine on my local machine** so far. Now to my problem:

I need to somehow distribute the view.php to every windows 7 computer in our office network.

1. We have absolutely no chance to install or execute any files (or
   local webservers) on our computer/network. Anything, that requires
   administrator rights will not work.
2. Simply getting the administrator password or asking about any
   changes to an administrator is out of question.
3. The oracle databases (read-only!) are secured with a firewall, which
   only permits connection requests from our static ip on our working
   machines.

Considering the mentioned limitations above: how can i make the php file accessible to the other machines in our office with a working external oracle database connection from the office ip without the possibility to install a webserver or in general without execute rights? is there anything else i can try?

Is there a way to publish the view.php on a remote webserver and somehow connect to the oracle databases from our local ip instead of failing by connecting from the webservers ip?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `view.php` a web page or a CLI (Command Line Interface) script

Comment: Depends how your local windows is modified - you can run some webserver without administrator-rights - on other ports e.g. – beside this there are not many options.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is a web page.

Comment: Then you dont actually need to do anything other than leave it on your machine and change the Apache config to allow any IP in your local network to access Apache. Probably would be a good idea to move the web server to another PC that is always left turned on

Comment: @CodeBrauer Thank you. Do you know any (portable) webservers that could work? EasyPHP Webserver requires admin rights. XAMPP portable is not working unfortunately. "netstat -a" in cmd displayed like 5 ports with the status "listening"

Comment: If you have a local DNS Server then you can add your PC's ip address to that with a domain name and create a Virtual Host in your Apache called that name

Comment: If no DNS Server then you will have to tell everybody the ip address of your PC or the Always on PC you move it all to

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, i will try this and then i will report the results :)

Comment: @Robama - check this out: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges (especially the Summary) – you can try other webserver but xampp portable on ports like `8888` worked anywhere I was - without any problems.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ive edited httpd.conf, added "Require ip ..." and "Listen ..." and now the whole thing is accessible from our network. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Zippedy doda, you are welcome